# how to change url format in angular js with pipe

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have url as below

```
http://localhost:9000/#/?name=angle,john,rechal&email=angle@gmail.com,john@gmail.com,rechal@gmail.com
```

how to replace or convert "," with pipe "|" in angular as below

```
http://localhost:9000/#/?name=angle|john|rechal&email=angle@gmail.com|john@gmail.com|rechal@gmail.com
```

Comment: x = x.replace(/,/g,'|')

Comment: is this valid if i pass it to backend @YOU

Answer (score 1):

Please see demo below

```
string = string.replace(/,/g,'|')
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope) {


  $scope.url = "http://localhost:9000/#/?name=angle,john,rechal&email=angle@gmail.com,john@gmail.com,rechal@gmail.com";
  $scope.aurl = $scope.url.replace(/,/g, '|')

});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="homeCtrl">
      <pre>{{url}}</pre>
      <pre>{{aurl}}</pre>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: when i have pasted pipe url in address bar i got something like this http://localhost:9000/#/?name=angle%7Cjohn%7Crechal&email=angle@gmail.com%7Cjohn@gmail.com%7Crechal@gmail.com instend of http://localhost:9000/#/?name=angle|john|rechal&email=angle@gmail.com|john@gmail.com|rechal@gmail.com

Comment: @TapanBavaliya I can't see difference ?